# Bar Plot : Legend and Axis issues

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to Plot the K-S Test result. Basically b\w the Significant and Insignificant variables. I need to Plot the legend, and the axis values in visible manner. If you can see the below plot, the Y- Axis values are not visible. Also the graph's Legend displays a dotted line. I need a solid squares or circle for Legend.

```
barplot(matrix, main="KS-Significance Test",
        xlab="Proportion b/w InSig vs Sig",
        ylab = 'Combinations',
        yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,5),
        cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab = 0.8,font = 2, horiz=TRUE,
        col=c("darkgreen","darkred"))
legend('topright',legend= c("Insignificant","Significant"),
       col= c("darkgreen","darkred"), lty = c(11,11),cex=0.8))
```

Please find the matrix data below by clicking the hyperlink.
[input data matrix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhTKd.png)
Also attaching the image of my barplot.
[image: Bar plot]

Comment: *"legend, and ... x axis values properly"*. Can you please explain what you mean by this? We can't read your mind, and "properly" can mean many things to many people.

Comment: @r2evans : Hi Thanks for getting back.  Agree you point. If you can see the above bar plot, My y-axis labels are not visible. Also, since I have 5 stacked bars here, my labels are not visible. I want to display it in proper readable manner.  Secondly, my legend is appearing as a dotted line. I need a solid squared or circled colour, which should be visible.  I guess, this explains my point.

Comment: Go ahead and edit your actual question with these explanations so everyone can clearly understand your question without having to scroll down to the comments section. I understood your legend problem: you wanted boxes instead of lines; now I understand your y-axis problem: the labels are missing; still do not understand the x-axis problem: you say the values are not displayed properly, what should they be?  You really need provide your data so we can troubleshoot the problem.  You can do this by pasting the output of 'dput(matrix)` into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Everyone. I have found the answer. Legend issues are also resolved.
here is the code.

```
barplot(matrix, main="KS-Significance Test",
        xlab="Proportion b/w InSig vs Sig",
        ylab = 'Combinations',
        ylim=c(0,270),
        cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab = 0.8,font = 4,
        names.arg = c("Cohort 2014-2015", "Cohort 2014-2016", "Cohort 2015-2016","Cohort 2015-2017","Cohort 2016-2017"),
        #horiz=TRUE,
        col=c("darkgreen","darkred"),
        legend = c("Insignificant","Significant"))
```

This completely satisfies my plot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill` instead of `col` and do not specify a line type `lty` if you do not want lines but box shapes -- i.e. wider lines that match your barplots :)

```
legend('topright',legend= c("Insignificant","Significant"),
   fill = c("darkgreen","darkred"), cex=0.8)
```

Otherwise, specify a line width `lwd`, here I use a solid line `lty=1` and `lwd=10` to get darker and wider lines.

```
legend('topright',legend= c("Insignificant","Significant"),
   col = c("darkgreen","darkred"), lty = 1, lwd = 10, cex = 0.8)
```

Comment: Thanks R.S.  Also can you help me with the Axis labels visibility

Comment: @PraveenKumarB for me to be able to help you with the axis labels, you need to provide the data you used to generate the plot.  See my comment under your original question. There are several reasons why your y-axis is not showing but I cannot tell without seeing the matrix you are plotting.

Comment: Please see the above question. I have added up a matrix.

Comment: Follow my instructions and type `dput(matrix)` into your terminal, and paste the output of this command onto your question.  An image of your matrix is not appropriate as it requires people to manually type in your data.  Providing a reproducible example is required whenever you ask a question in SO.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I have followed  your instructions and provided dput(matrix). Also attached the image.

Comment: Did you just copy the barplot code from someplace?  The y-axis and labels are not showing because you set `yaxt="n"`, meaning you asked for the y-axis to be suppressed in the plot.  Look at help file `?par` to understand what the graphical parameters that you can set.  If you remove `yaxt="n"`, y-labels will show, then you should look at setting `las` parameter so the y-labels are horizontal and have room to be printed.  All of this in the `par` help file. Similarly, look at `?legend` to understand how to adjust `legend` parameters.